# irobot create3 topics not found after setup in macos multipass vm

Tags: ros-humble, macos, create3, irobot, multipass

I have a Mac OS `14.1` and I'm seting up irobot Create3 for the first time. I've confirmed the robot works using the [python web playground](https://edu.irobot.com/learning-library/create-3-web-playground-for-python).

I've installed Multipass `1.12.2+mac` and created an Ubuntu 22.04 instance and installed ROS2 per [the robot humble setup guide](https://iroboteducation.github.io/create3_docs/setup/ubuntu2204/). I created the multipass instance with this command:

```
multipass launch --name=create3 --cpus=2 --disk=20GiB
```

When listing the topics, I don't see any of the expected irobot topics

```
ros2 topic list
```

Actual:

```
/parameter_events 
/rosout
```

Expected:

```
/battery_state
/cliff_intensity
/cmd_audio ...
```

The VM info `multipass info create3`:

```
Name:           create3
State:          Running
IPv4:           10.211.67.3
                172.17.0.1
Release:        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Image hash:     054db2d88c45 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
CPU(s):         2
Load:           0.00 0.14 0.12
Disk usage:     8.8GiB out of 19.3GiB
Memory usage:   248.8MiB out of 3.8GiB
Mounts:         --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Network Reccommendations](https://iroboteducation.github.io/create3_docs/setup/network-config/), Bridged Network is required:

> While many virtualization applications default to a "shared" or "NAT" network connection, this type of connection will not allow ROS 2 to communicate with the Create® 3 robot. Instead, a bridged network connection should be used for the virtual machine.

Creating a multipass instance with `--bridged` fixes:

```
multipass launch --name=create3-bridged --bridged --cpus=2 --disk=20GiB
```

VM Infor `multipass info create3-bridged`:

```
Name:           create3-bridged
State:          Running
IPv4:           10.211.67.5
                192.168.0.153
Release:        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Image hash:     054db2d88c45 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
CPU(s):         2
Load:           1.38 0.90 0.47
Disk usage:     2.5GiB out of 19.3GiB
Memory usage:   204.5MiB out of 951.1MiB
```

Notice previously, the IP was `172.17.0.1` but now is `192.168.0.153` which matches my home network.

`ros2 topic list` now produces:

```
/battery_state
/cliff_intensity
/cmd_audio
/cmd_lightring
/cmd_vel
/dock
/hazard_detection
/imu
/interface_buttons
/ir_intensity
/ir_opcode
/kidnap_status
/mobility_monitor/transition_event
/mouse
/odom
/parameter_events
/robot_state/transition_event
/rosout
/slip_status
/static_transform/transition_event
/stop_status
/tf
/tf_static
/wheel_status
/wheel_ticks
/wheel_vels
```